# SQL expression is of wrong type

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Trying to run the following on SQL developer

```
declare
    type hType is table of number not null
        index by BINARY_INTEGER;
    items_v hType;
    references_v hType;
    keyId number;

begin   
    keyId := 1234567;

    select i.item bulk collect into items_v
    from items i
    where i.item_id = ...;

    select j.reference bulk collect into references_v
    from references j
    where j.reference = ..
        and j.item in items_v;
end;
```

> I get ORA-06550: line 23, column 31: PLS-00382: expression is of the
>   wrong type

Even though `j.item` and `i.item` are also of type  `NUMBER`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until 11g, you cannot declare a `TYPE` in `PLSQL` scope and use it in `SQL` statement within a PLSQL block. You need to declare the `TYPE` under the scope of `SQL` , if you want to use it under `PLSQL` block. Also when you wanted to use one collection in `IN` clause, then `MEMBER OF` can be used. See below:

Type Created in SQL Scope.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HTYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER NOT NULL ;
        /

Type created.
```

Anonymous Block

```
SQL> DECLARE   
  2       ITEMS_V                       HTYPE;
  3       REFERENCES_V                  HTYPE;
  4       KEYID                         NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6       KEYID := 1234567;
  7  
  8       SELECT I.ITEM
  9       BULK COLLECT INTO ITEMS_V
 10         FROM ITEMS I
 11        WHERE I.ITEM_ID = 1;
 12  
 13       SELECT J.REFERENCE
 14       BULK COLLECT INTO REFERENCES_V
 15         FROM REFERENCES J
 16        WHERE J.REFERENCE = 1
 17        AND J.ITEM MEMBER OF ITEMS_V;--<--Used Member of to check elements of colection
 18  END;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You can use use `IN` clause as:

```
SQL> DECLARE   
  2       ITEMS_V                       HTYPE;
  3       REFERENCES_V                  HTYPE;
  4       KEYID                         NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6       KEYID := 1234567;
  7  
  8       SELECT I.ITEM
  9       BULK COLLECT INTO ITEMS_V
 10         FROM ITEMS I
 11        WHERE I.ITEM_ID = 1;
 12  
 13       SELECT J.REFERENCE
 14       BULK COLLECT INTO REFERENCES_V
 15         FROM REFERENCES J
 16        WHERE J.REFERENCE = 1
 17        AND J.ITEM IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(ITEMS_V)); --<-- Used IN Clause.
 18  END;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you @XING, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In the REFERENCES part of your query, you can't use ITEMS_V collection like that; consider using something like this instead:

```
for i in items_v.first .. items_v.last loop
  select j.reference bulk collect into references_v
    from references j
    where j.reference = ..
        and j.item_id = items_v(i);
end loop;
```

There might be a smarter way to do that (hopefully, someone else will show you how), but this should work as well.